# Volley en Android me registra dos veces

Tags: java, android, android-volley

estoy generando registros de un Inventario el problema es que por el tipo de BD que me proporcionan debo  hacer dos registros.

---

-el primero generar un registro que me retorna un valor ID y volley lo recoge correctamente.

---

-el segundo registro toma el valor tomado anteriormente y con otro conjunto de datos se guarda.

---

El problema está en el segundo registro algunas veces registra normal y otras veces registra doble, he intentado agregar un policy suponiendo que el motivo por el que registra dos veces es algún retraso en servidor, falla en internet o otra razón que pueda obligar a volley a volver a enviar la petición post, actualmente y supongo que de una manera no recomendable lo único que ayuda a minimizar los registros dobles es retrasar el segundo registro, en pocas palabras que el botón que genera el segundo registro salga unos segundos después lo que haría la experiencia de usuario muy mala.

**Este es el segundo registro**

```
public void crearArticulo(int nombre,String descripcion, int marca,String modelo,String serie,String observaciones, int area, String UUID,String valor){
String oficio;

oficio="S/O";

String LAURL="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/crearArticulo";
try{
    JSONObject regis = new JSONObject();
    regis.put("nombre_id", nombre);
    regis.put("descripcion",descripcion);
    regis.put("marca_id",marca);
    regis.put("modelo",modelo);
    regis.put("serie",serie);
    regis.put("estado_fisico",Festado);
    regis.put("observacion",observaciones);
    regis.put("area_id",area);
    regis.put("uuid",UUID);
    regis.put("estatus",valor);
    regis.put("oficio",oficio);

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    //Response
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            LAURL,
            regis,
            response -> {
                String eese=response.optString("id");

              // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eese, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            },
            error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    )
    {
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

}catch (Exception e){}
}//CrearArticulo
```

**Este es el primer registro**

```
 public void crearUbicacion(){
    Inumero=Integer.parseInt(edtnumero.getText().toString());

    String url="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/crearArea";
    try{
        JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
        postparams.put("numero", Inumero);
        postparams.put("tipo_area_id",ItipoArea);
        postparams.put("nivel_id",Inivel);
        postparams.put("trabajador_id",Itrabajador);

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                postparams,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                            FIDArea=Integer.parseInt(response.optString("id"));

                    }//Response
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
        )
        {
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeout=30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }catch (Exception e){}




}//crearUbicacion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El problema es sin duda que la respuesta de las peticiones es asíncrona**, por lo tanto, debes asegurar obtener el resultado de una petición para realizar la siguiente.

**Al usar [`Volley`](https://google.github.io/volley/simple.html) puedes obtener el resultado de la respuesta dentro de [`onResponse()`](https://google.github.io/volley/request.html)**, en consecuencia, aquí es donde debes llamar el siguiente proceso para asegurar obtener el resultado de la primera respuesta:

```
...
...
JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                postparams,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                            FIDArea=Integer.parseInt(response.optString("id"));

                      //*Aquí llama el siguiente proceso : CrearArticulo() !


                    }//Response
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
        )
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: solucione por completo el error gracias por la respuesta.